# Anyone successfully get the NIC Firmware version from Windows OS level?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

Anyone successfully get the NIC Firmware version from Windows OS level?
We can get the driver version using get-netadapter but how about firmware version?

get-netadapter, get-wmiobject and ciminstance

Comment: Are you able to see it anywhere on Windows itself?

Comment: I can see firmware of other devices but not NIC.. It could be hidden somewhere else which i dont know

Comment: It would be dependent on the manufacturer and if that's even exposed through the OS. Some drivers have the firmware version listed somewhere in the driver version string; *usually at the end*. This is still dependent on if it's exposed through it or not. I would suggest checking the Manufacturers website. If there's a program that can get you that info, you can do it programatically - *whether is a 3rd party software or if native to windows*.